# Create a GridTooltip-Template

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have a problem by displaying a Grid-Tooltip.

Here is my Code:

```
<dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:CardView x:Name="viewAgreementMonitoring" ShowTotalSummary="True" ShowSearchPanelMode="Always" ShowGroupPanel="False" >
         <dxg:CardView.CardHeaderTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid >
                     <Grid.Style>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                             <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                 <Setter.Value>
                                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                                         <StackPanel>
                                             <TextBlock>txt1</TextBlock>
                                                 <TextBlock>
                                                     Red: The Contractdurationend is expired
                                                     Yellow: The Contractdurationend will expire in less than 12 Months
                                                     Green: The Contractdurationend takes place in more than 12 Months
                                                 </TextBlock>
                                                 <Label Content="{Binding vesselID}" ContentStringFormat="VesselID: {0}" />
                                         </StackPanel>
                                     </ControlTemplate>
                                 </Setter.Value>
                             </Setter>
                         </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.vesselDescription}" Background="{Binding Data.background}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Data.vesselCustomer}" Background="{Binding Data.background}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dxg:CardView.CardHeaderTemplate>
```

When i run the Application the Grid-Tooltip displays:

"System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate"

Where is the Error in my code?

Comment: Where are you setting the data context for the bindings?

Comment: I set the ItemsSource and the data context in code behind.

Comment: The Solution of my question is to set the Tooltip otherwise. When I use <Grid.ToolTip> <Stackpanel> UI ELEMNTS </Stackpanel> </Grid.ToolTip/> instead of <Grid.Style> it worked for me.